# How to create Custompreference variable in powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Powershell has lot of preference variable like ErrorPreference, VerbosePreference and DebugPreference.

Is it possible to create custompreference variable ?

The case is as below

```
function Write-Log {
 param(
  $message,
  [switch] $tee
 )

Write-output $message | Out-content -path <LogFile> -Append 
if( $tee)
{
 Write-host $Message
}

}
```

This function may be called in multiple places . Passing -Tee switch in every place is not simple. If there is custompreference as $TeePreference = "Continue" then i don't need to pass -Tee every place. Also if i need to stop I can do $TeePreference = "SilentlyContinue".

Comment: I undurstand your question in the general case, but in your example case, why don't you use VerbosePreference.

Comment: @JPBlanc you are right. for this particular case verbose preference is enough.